# Не работает SlickSlider в Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Суть проблемы. Если запускаю сайт "Go Live" через VSCode, то всё отлично работает. Но если открываю сам файл index.html из папки, то слайдер перестаёт работать. В чём может быть проблема??

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема заключается в путях к файлам, которые используются в вашем слайдере. Когда вы запускаете сайт VSCode, сервер раздает файлы с помощью локального хоста, и пути к файлам будут относительными от корня вашего сервера.

Но в момент, когда вы открываете файл, к примеру, index.html напрямую из папки, браузер рассматривает пути к файлам как относительные относительно текущего URL-адреса страницы.

Попробуйте пересмотреть ваши пути пути к файлам, и возможно, проблема найдется :D